# I get connection refused nodejs docker nginx and googleDDNS server

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, networking

This is the first time I ask anything on stackoverflow, but basically I have a bunch of docker containers setup that work well with nginx and google DDNS servers. Recently I've tried to add a nodejs container for a project and I keep getting connection refused error. The weird part is that the ip address I'm getting on the upstream server has nothing to do with my node container. Here are my settings for everything:

docker-compose for nodejs:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  ddnsTestNode: #Change this line
    image: 'dragoncube/google-domains-ddns'
    container_name: ddnsTestNode #Change this line
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: /media/MainData/ddns/test #Change this line
        target: /config/google-domains-ddns.conf
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime
    networks:
      - mainNetwork  
  testnode:
    image: "node:8"
    user: "node"
    container_name: testnode
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - /path/to/saved/node/app:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    expose:
      - "8081"
    command: "npm start"
networks:
  mainNetwork:
    external: true
```

for NGINX (just the corresponding server):

```
server {

listen 443;
listen [::]:443;
server_name MY_SERVER_HIDDEN_FOR_QUESTION;

ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

ssl on;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
client_max_body_size 10000G;

location  / {

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://testnode:8081/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance, I really tried looking for an answer but couldn't find anything with my specific problem. Every other container I have such as seafile or gitlab works with my setup, but a basic node container doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, turns out I didn't specify

```
  networks:
   - mainNetwork
```

in my testnode docker-compose file